# How could I optimize this code to not "freeze" my computer?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{

    XFORM blah;
    blah.eM22 = 1.0f;
    blah.eDx = 0.0f;
    blah.eDy = 0.0f;
    blah.eM11 = 1.0f;
    float blahm1 = 0.0;
    float blahm2 = 0.0;
    HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    HBITMAP cross = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Death\\My Documents\\45Hand.bmp") ,IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    HBITMAP crossmask = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Death\\My Documents\\45Hand2.bmp") ,IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    while (1)
    {
        HDC hdc_x = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
        blahm2 = (blahm2 + 0.0001f);
        blah.eM12 = blahm1;
        blah.eM21 = blahm2;
        SelectObject(hdc, cross);
        SetGraphicsMode(hdc_x, GM_ADVANCED);
        SetWorldTransform(hdc_x, &blah);
        BitBlt(hdc_x,512,384,800,703,hdc,0,0,SRCAND);
        ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP,hdc_x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I wouldn't expect this to lag so insanely, but when I execute 2 instances of this program at once my whole computer practically becomes unresponsive, for example if I were to right click under those circumstances it would literally take approximately 10 seconds for the menu to appear.

Comment: Why would you run two instances of it? Why would you run *any* instances of it?

Comment: You're asking the computer to do something as fast as it possible can, until it explodes. And you're surprised that it eats up resources and slows things down?

Comment: @NikBougalis when I didn't have SetWorldTransform in there it didn't cause things to become unresponsive, so if the while loop alone is whats causing it to become unresponsive why wasn't it unresponsive when I didn't have SetWorldTransform in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The endless loop in itself might be a problem, but I suppose the actual problem (assuming you do want it to loop endlessly!) comes more from the fact that it's a **tight AND endless loop**, and that it doesn't allow the scheduler to give back control to other tasks.

To solve this, you should ensure that your loop allows for other tasks to get a chance to run.

"Sleeping" is usually an easy solution, or doing actual synchronization between your threads.

Comment: I think this might be the problem, before when I wasn't using setworldtransform this ran without causing freezing.

Comment: @user2462027: Maybe, it's hard to say without knowing the internals of the functions. Even a single-threaded program with a `while (42 == 42) {}` would loop forever and freeze the computer badly, because of the same reasons. It that was indeed your problem come back later to mark an answer as accepted, or give us more details so we can keep troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the endless loop:

```
while (1)
{
    // Repeat this code forever...
}
```

Comment: The endless loop was intended to be there.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options here :

1. As mentioned by others, add a break by some way, at your while loop
2. Use threads, with a sleep(nb_milliseconds) inside your while loop to smooth CPU resources usage.

The second option has the advantage to allow you to run two instances of your treatment at the same time from a single instance of the program by the way.

**WARNING :** Threads are not handled the same depending on the compiler or the platform, but you'll find out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're trying to do here; but *this is not the way Windows programs are meant to be written.*

If you look at [this sample program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you'll see that it has a bit of code which handles the `WM_PAINT` message. That's where your code goes.

**Edited to add**

I hadn't noticed the drawn object moves. So one of the better ways to do this:

1) Use `SetTimer()` to send yourself a message when the position should be updated

2) When you get the `WM_TIMER` message, calculate the new position and call `InvalidateRect()` (which tells Windows there's something to repaint)

3) In the `WM_PAINT` handler, do the actual drawing.

The point of all this is to let Windows do the scheduling for you, keeping the UI reponsive.

Comment: So how do I know which recursive functions should go in a windowsprocedure callback rather than a loop and why?

Comment: Your code is not recursive, and it only needs to be called when the screen needs to be repainted; that's what goes in the `WM_PAINT` handler.

Comment: but the screen does need to be repainted each time the while loop is executed because it changes where the shape will be drawn a little due to `blahm2 = (blahm2 + 0.0001f);` so will this still apply?